# Como usar websocket servidor- servidor en node.js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, websocket, blockchain

Hola soy nuevo en node y me preguntaba como puedo consumir un servicio de websockets desde node, ósea servidor-servidor, el segundo es un servidor externo aquí el link: https://blockchain.info/api/api_websocket, Muchas gracias comunidad por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero usar la libreria 'ws' que esta disponible en npm: `npm install ws`. Luego puedes consumir la api de websockets de esta forma:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv");

ws.on('open', function() {
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({"op":"ping"}));
});

ws.on('message', function(message) {
  console.log('Received: ' + message);
});

ws.on('close', function(code) {
  console.log('Disconnected: ' + code);
});

ws.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log('Error: ' + error.code);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Service para angular 7
`

```
import { Observable, Subject, Observer,  } from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators'

interface IbitcoinRecibidos {
  saldo: number;
  hash: string;
  confirmaciones:number;
}

const BLOCKCHAIN_URL = "wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv";



class RecibiendoPagos {

 public wallet=['14EFnam7mxMZCvUWDG8urRK7CANbi5mab6'];

 private subject: Subject<MessageEvent>;
 public messages: Subject<IbitcoinRecibidos>;
  public hash:string='';
 public saldo:number=0;
 public confirmaciones:number=0;

 router:Router;
  constructor(){
    this.subject = this.create(BLOCKCHAIN_URL);
    this.router =Router();

     this.messages = <Subject<IbitcoinRecibidos>>
      this.connect(BLOCKCHAIN_URL)
    .pipe(
      map((response: MessageEvent):IbitcoinRecibidos => {

        let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        const salida = data.x.out;
        const cuentasalida = salida.length;
        this.hash = data.x.hash;

        for(let i=0; i<cuentasalida; i++){
          var direccion = data.x.out[i].addr;
          if(direccion == this.wallet){
            const monto = data.x.out[i].value;
            this.saldo = monto / 100000000;
          }}
          return {
            saldo: this.saldo,
            hash: this.hash,
            confirmaciones:this.confirmaciones
          };
      }
    ));
  }



  public connect(BLOCKCHAIN_URL:string):Subject<MessageEvent> {
    if (!this.subject) {
      this.subject = this.create(BLOCKCHAIN_URL);
      console.log("Successfully connected: " + BLOCKCHAIN_URL);
    }
    return this.subject;
  } 


  private create(BLOCKCHAIN_URL:string): Subject<MessageEvent> {
    let ws = new WebSocket(BLOCKCHAIN_URL);

    let observable = Observable.create((obs: Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
      ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
      ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
      ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
      return ws.close.bind(ws);
    });
    let observer = {

      next: () => {
        if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          ws.send(
            JSON.stringify({"op":"addr_sub","addr":this.wallet})
          );
        }
      }
    };
    return Subject.create(observer, observable);
  }
}`
```

Comment: Buenas, las respuestas que son solo código son recibidas como de mala calidad puesto que no explican la solución. Por favor edita la respuesta con su explicación